# ¿Cómo guardar la SESSION del captcha globalmente, para luego poder ocultar campos del formulario?

Tags: php

Lo que trato de evitar es que el sistema de verificación captcha vuelva aparecer al recargar la página o si el usuario vuelve, para ello necesito guardar globalmente que ese usuario valido correctamente el código captcha en una `SESSION`.

Hasta ahora he logrado validar los datos ingresados, si el usuario ingresa datos erróneos se imprime el mensaje de error.

```
<?php
        $message = NULL;
        if (isset($_POST)) {
            if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["code_captcha"]) && $_POST["code_captcha"]!=$_SESSION["code_captcha"]) {
                $message = "The characters entered are incorrect";
            }
        }

        if($message!="") { echo '<div class="error">'.$message.'</div>'; }

        echo '<form action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <img src="image.php"/>
            <input name="code_captcha" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Validar" formnovalidate>
        </form>';
```

Solo me hace falta validar los datos correctos, para así poder ocultar el formulario o algunos campos input del formulario, me podrían explicar como validar este ultimo paso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice pruebas en localhost, y he adaptado un poco el código, a mí me funciona bien.

He usado en vede `<img src="image.php"/>` una sesión `$_SESSION["code_captcha"] = '124ADS';`, para hacer la prueba.

También añadí el atributo `name` al input submit por si usas más formularios, saber cuál estas enviando.

`<input type='submit' name='validar_captcha' value='Validar'>`

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // Iniciamos valor de tu captcha
  $_SESSION["code_captcha"] = '124ADS';    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php        
    
        $message = NULL;
        
        // Comprobar si esta iniciado nuestro Formulario
        if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['validar_captcha'])) {                
                            
            // Comprobar inputs
            // He usado un || (or) envede un &&, ya que esta diciendo si esta vacio y si tambien no coincide
            if(empty($_POST["code_captcha"]) || $_POST["code_captcha"] != $_SESSION["code_captcha"]) {                    
                $message = "The characters entered are incorrect";
            } else {
                // Si todo esta correcto creas la sesion para evitar el captcha.
                $_SESSION['captcha_check'] = true;
            }   
            
            if($message!="") { echo '<div class="error">'.$message.'</div>'; } 
            
        }     
    
        
        // Muestras formulario captcha si no es valido.
        if (!isset($_SESSION['captcha_check'])) {
                
            $captcha = $_SESSION['code_captcha'];
                
            echo "
                <form action=# method=post autocomplete=off enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                    <input type='text' value = '$captcha'>
                    <input name='code_captcha' type='text'>
                    <input type='submit' name='validar_captcha' value='Validar'>
                </form>
            ";
        }
    ?>
    
    <!-- Otro formulario -->
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <input type='text' placeholder="Nombre">
        <?php // Ocultar este input si el captcha es valido
            if (!isset($_SESSION['captcha_check'])) {
                echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Apellidos'>";
            }
        ?>
        
        <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='guardar'>
    </form>
</body>
```

Para ocultar un input, podrías hacer algo así:

```
// Mientras no existe la sesion 'captcha_check' mostramos input
if (!isset($_SESSION['captcha_check'])) {
   echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Apellidos'>";
}
```

*Respuesta contador*

Si deseas llevar un control de intentos fallidos sin usar una Base de datos, lo podrías hacer mediante una sesión.

```
// Iniciamos contador en 1
if (!isset($_SESSION['contador'])) {
     $_SESSION['contador'] = 1;
// Contador ya existe, incrementamos.
} else {
    $_SESSION['contador'] ++;
}
```

**Implementamos el contador al ejemplo:**

```
        // Comprobar inputs
        if(empty($_POST["code_captcha"]) || $_POST["code_captcha"] != $_SESSION["code_captcha"]) {   
            // Iniciamos contador en 1
            if (!isset($_SESSION['contador'])) {
                $_SESSION['contador'] = 1;
            // Contador ya existe, incrementamos.
            } else {
                $_SESSION['contador'] ++;
            }
            
            // Obtener valor del contador.
            $contador = (isset($_SESSION['contador']))
               ? $_SESSION['contador']
               : 0
            ;
            // Mensaje
            $message = "The characters entered are incorrect, llevas $contador intento/s fallido/s";
        } else {
            // Destruimos la sesion de intentos si lo deseas asi.
            unset($_SESSION['contador']);
            
            // Si todo esta correcto creas la sesion para evitar el captcha.
            $_SESSION['captcha_check'] = true;
        }   
        
        if($message!="") { echo '<div class="error">'.$message.'</div>'; }
```

Comment: @J.Mick si revise tu ejemplo en la respuesta de RVera y vi que entro en el `else`, hice unas pruebas en localhost, y me paso lo mismo, te e dejado un ejemplo diferente. Ya me comentas.

Comment: ya le reviso amigo que

Comment: funciona perfectamente, no es necesario el uso de: `unset($_SESSION['captcha_check']);`

Comment: @J.Mick según tu pregunta quieres que el captcha desaparece si este esta verificado correctamente, 1. cuando se recarga la página y 2. cuando el usuario vuelve. Si usaras el `unset` como te mencionan en otra respuesta, si por ejemplo navegas a otra página y luego vuelves a la página del formulario donde tienes el captcha, el usuario debería volver a verificar el captcha, ya que va usar la línea de `unset` y eso no lo deseas, si deseas que es solo al recargar la página entonces sí que podrías usar `if (count($_POST) > 0) {} else {unset($_SESSION['captcha_check']); }`

Comment: si amigo tienes toda la razón, como le creo un contador por sesiones por cada falla, no deseo almacenar en la base de datos solo un pequeño control por sessiones, para contar cuantos intentos fallidos obtuvo al llenar el código de validación

Comment: @J.Mick te actualizo mi respuesta añadiendo un contador para llevar un control de intentos fallidos.

Comment: si por favor, gracias

Comment: @J.Mick te he dejado un apartado **Respuesta contador**, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes el proceso en que verifica la respuesta captcha, puedes guardar un flag en el mismo momento:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    if(isset($_POST["code_captcha"])){
        if ($_POST["code_captcha"] == $_SESSION["code_captcha"]) {
            $_SESSION['captchaok'] = true;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['captchaok'] = false; // o unset($_SESSION['captchaok'])
            $message = "The characters entered are incorrect";
        }
    } 
}
```

Luego en la parte del código donde muestras el desafío captcha primero verificas el estado de la variable $_SESSION['captchaok'].

```
if(isset($_SESSION['captchaok']) && $_SESSION['captchaok'] == true){ // o if(empty($_SESSION['captchaok']))...
    //Código para mostrar el captcha o lo que necesites cuando no está validado.
}
```

Comment: De esa manera siempre va estar verdadero `$_SESSION['captchaok'] = true;` porque va activar esto `} else {
            $_SESSION['captchaok'] = true;
       }`

Comment: @J.Mick Dicha sesión se pone **false** cuando el captcha no coincide o esta vacío. En caso de que todos los datos estén correctos se pone en **true**. El problema que veo es que deberías de actualizar la página para que dicha sesión coja el valor true o false modificado o podrías usar AJAX.

Comment: @D.Bulten no amigo, va estar siempre `true` porque está dando `false` en el `else` del `if` aquí te demuestro la prueba https://ideone.com/nu8EsU

Comment: @J.Mick Y luego la ultima parte, la sentencia `if` debe estar en `false`, para mostrar el captcha, es decir, `if(isset($_SESSION['captchaok']) && $_SESSION['captchaok'] == false){ //Mostrar el captcha a verificar }`

Comment: @D.Bulten pero esto no deja de seguir siendo error, porque es ilógico que esté verdadero la verificación cuando esto no ha sucedido, en eso voy amigo.

Comment: @J.Mick pues es un poco raro que siempre este `true` ya que el `else` lo ignora si el input del captcha no coincida con la sesión del captcha, en la línea, `$_POST["code_captcha"] !=  $_SESSION["code_captcha"]`, quizás te podemos ayudar si subes todo el código, desde donde creas la sesión del captcha, a ver si el error viene desde tu sesión que no vemos como lo creas, ni `session_start();`.

Comment: @D.Bulten no revisó el link que te pasé? Esta claro, se da solo true porque a este `if` `if(isset($_POST["code_captcha"]) && $_POST["code_captcha"]!= $_SESSION["code_captcha"]) {` le han puesto un `else` obviamente va ejecutar true amigo, porque se le está poniendo una condición cuando no cumple con la otra. Es todo el código en mi pregunta, solo que no le agregué `session_star();` pero el error está clarito.

Comment: @J.Mick edité un poco el código para mejorar la lógica de "siempre true" que comentabas. Debería ser algo asi. Solo ten en cuenta que las respuestas son una orientación, no necesariamente textual. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas considerar todas las posibilidades:

- Si se está enviando el formulario:

  1. Verificar que no se ha validado previamente ($_SESSION['captchaok'])
  2. Asegurar que el código viene en $_POST (isset)
  3. Comparar el valor de $_POST con el guardado en sesión
  4. Si todo está correcto, creas la variable de sesión
- Si algo falla o no se ha enviado aún el formulario, te aseguras de que no exista la variable en sesión

```
$message = '';
if(count($_POST) > 0) {
    if(
        !isset($_SESSION['captchaok'])    // No está en sesión Y
        && (!isset($_POST["code_captcha"])   // (No aparece en $_POST O
        || $_POST["code_captcha"]!= $_SESSION["code_captcha"] // El código es incorrecto)
    ) {
        $message = "The characters entered are incorrect";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['captchaok'] = true;
   }
} else {
    // No se ha ejecutado el formulario, es la primera vez que se va a mostrar
    // Eliminar variable, por si quedó de una sesión previa
    unset($_SESSION['captchaok']);
}
```

Cuando muestras el formulario verificas que **NO** existe la variable en sesión para mostrar los campos:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['captchaok'])) {
    // No existe la variable porque:
    // -- Es la primera ejecución
    // -- O el código introducido fue incorrecto
    // Aquí muestras el captcha y cualquier otro campo necesario
}
```